# Ember installations becomes broken after ember-cli-foundation-sass installation

Tags: ember.js

I try to use ember-cli-foundation-sass. But ember installation becomes broken after I add this extension. I works without ember-cli-foundation-sass installation. ember server works fine without it. But does not work with this extension.

node version: 5.1.0
ember-cli version : 1.13.13

I see jquery version in bower.json file:  "jquery": "^1.11.3",

Look at console output, please.

```
igor@hp-laptop ~/projects/extending-todomvc                                                                                 [9:12:38] 
ember install:addon ember-cli-foundation-sass                                                                   ⬡ 5.1.0 [±master]
version: 1.13.13
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
This command has been deprecated. Please use `ember install <addonName>` instead.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
installing ember-cli-foundation-sass
  install bower package foundation
Installing browser packages via Bower...
  cached git://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation.git#5.5.3
  cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
  cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.3
  cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
  cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
  conflict Unable to find suitable version for jquery
    1) jquery >= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0
    2) jquery ^1.11.3
    3) jquery >= 2.1.0
    4) jquery >=1.2
    5) jquery >=1.6
[?] Answer: 2
Installed browser packages via Bower.
  create app/styles/app.scss
  install packages ember-cli-sass, broccoli-clean-css
Installing packages for tooling via npmCan not download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/linux-x64-node-5.1/binding.node
Installing packages for tooling via npm.module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/igor/projects/extending-todomvc/node_modules/ember-cli-sass/node_modules/broccoli-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
Build failed
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Installed addon package.

igor@hp-laptop ~/projects/extending-todomvc                                                                                 [9:16:22] 
$ ember s                                                                                                      ⬡ 5.1.0 [±master ●●]
`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at getBinding (/home/igor/projects/extending-todomvc/node_modules/ember-cli-sass/node_modules/broccoli-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igor/projects/extending-todomvc/node_modules/ember-cli-sass/node_modules/broccoli-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igor/projects/extending-todomvc/node_modules/ember-cli-sass/node_modules/broccoli-sass/index.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in previous console log

> Can not download file from
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/linux-x64-node-5.1/binding.node

I have downgraded nodejs to version 0.12.8 and it works now.

Instead this error i have seen

> Installing packages for tooling via npm...linux-x64-node-0.12 exists;
>   testing

Problem has solved. Thank you all!